# Defining a PHP function dynamically

Tags: php

I'm trying to define a PHP function within an array:

```
foreach($redirects as $from => $to) {
  array_push($routes, array(
    'pattern' => $from,
    'action' => function($to) {
     header::redirect($to, 301);
    }
  ));
}
```

But I get an error `Missing argument 1 for $to`. Basically I should define $to within the function. How can I make this work in PHP?

Comment: `function($to) use ($to) { ... }`

Comment: Aljaz  i am unable to reproduce your problem,.Can you provide some example link where i can check

Answer (score 0):

Store `$to` as well in the array and use `call_user_func($func, $param)` to call the function as follows:

```
foreach($redirects as $from => $to) {
  array_push($routes, array(
    'pattern' => $from,
    'to'     => $to,
    'action' => function($to) {
     header::redirect($to, 301);
    }
  ));
}
```

call it as:

```
call_user_func($routes[1]['action'], $routes[1]['to']);
```

Let's say your $redirects is

```
$redirects= ['/home' => 'index.php', 'login' => 'login.php'];
```

you can use it as:

```
$current_route = '/login';
foreach($routes as $index => $route) {
    if($route['pattern'] == $current_route) {
        call_user_func($route['action'], $routes['to']);
    }
}
```

Good Luck!